# XSLT XPath issue when getting grand parent of an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm new to xslt and I'm writing a xslt to replace a value of a node with a value of some other node. The XML is as follows,

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
       <ShipAddress>
          <EMail>a@b.com</EMail>
       </ShipAddress>

       <OrderData>
          <Description>xxxx</Description>
       </OrderData>
    </Order>

    <Order>
    ......
    </Order>

</Orders>
```

I want to replace the value of Description with Email for each order. I've created below xslt for the transformation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Orders/Order/OrderData/Description/text()">
     <xsl:value-of select="../../ShipAddress/EMail"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the Description field is not updating. Please let me know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the solution to your problem is a good thing, but your conclusion is wrong.

> In xslt, in order to get the grand parent we should use ../../../*

Not really. The point is that you are actually looking for the grand grand parent of the text content of `Description`, namely `Order`. The grand parent of `Orders/Order/OrderData/Description/text()` is `OrderData`. But `OrderData` does not have an element `EMail` as a child - that's why your approach failed.

Below is a slightly improved stylesheet. It matches `Description` more directly and uses the `ancestor::` axis instead of a series of `..`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Description/text()">
     <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Order/ShipAddress/EMail"/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Input**

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
       <ShipAddress>
          <EMail>a@b.com</EMail>
       </ShipAddress>

       <OrderData>
          <Description>xxxx</Description>
       </OrderData>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Orders>
   <Order>
      <ShipAddress>
         <EMail>a@b.com</EMail>
      </ShipAddress>
      <OrderData>
         <Description>a@b.com</Description>
      </OrderData>
   </Order>
</Orders>
```